# Installing Anaconda python 3.7

Tags: python

I am trying to install `anaconda` but I am getting this error

```
PREFIX=/home/ofasorgu/anaconda3
installing: python-3.7.3-h0371630_0 ...
tar: bin/python3.7-config: Cannot create symlink to `python3.7m-config': No such file or directory
tar: bin/pydoc: Cannot create symlink to `pydoc3.7': No such file or directory
tar: bin/pydoc3: Cannot create symlink to `pydoc3.7': No such file or directory
tar: bin/idle3: Cannot create symlink to `idle3.7': No such file or directory
tar: bin/2to3: Cannot create symlink to `2to3-3.7': No such file or directory
tar: bin/pyvenv: Cannot create symlink to `pyvenv-3.7': No such file or directory
tar: bin/python3: Cannot create symlink to `python3.7': No such file or directory
tar: bin/python: Cannot create symlink to `python3.7': No such file or directory
tar: lib/pkgconfig/python3.pc: Cannot create symlink to `python-3.7.pc': No such file or directory
tar: bin/python3.7m: Cannot create symlink to `python3.7': No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Can you give me advice how to fix it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why downvote ? Can you give some explanation ? What more shall I provide ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to run it as sudo?

More information about you OS would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install dependencies before installing anaconda. I think installing `virtualenv` and `libpython3.7-dev` should work.

Make sure you install these for the right python version using `python3.7 -m pip install [DEPENDENCY}`.

For example:

```
python3.7 -m pip install libpython3.7-dev virtualenv
```

Assuming you are trying to install anaconda for Python3.7 in your system. If not, make sure to install it for the python (with dependencies) present in your system.